# Sum column of values where separate column contains duplicate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to sum all values in `Column A` where `Column B` is a duplicate.

[image: screenshot of Excel]

Above is a sample of the data. `Column B` has urls and `Column A` has counts for the urls. What I want is to sum the values in `Column A` for duplicate values in `Column B`.

**Example:**

The output for *_.apelabs.net* should be 6.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the function `=COUNTIF(Range,Criteria)`
[Here](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/how-to-use-countif-instead-of-vlookup/) is a link that shows a usage example.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andresson stated, if you're trying to ***count*** the number of times a specific url appears, you might want to use the `COUNTIF` function: `=COUNTIF(range, criteria)`.

**COUNTIF Example**: 

Using `=COUNTIF(B:B, "_.apelabs.net")`

would return 3 in your sample data (assuming your image includes the only instances of *"_.apelabs.net"*).

This example of the `COUNTIF` function is the same as saying, "***count*** the total number of times a cell in `Column B` (i.e. `B:B`) **equals** *"_.apelabs.net"*."

However, if you're wanting to ***sum*** together all the values in `Column A` where the corresponding url in `Column B` matches the given criteria, you'll want the `SUMIF` function: `=SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])`.

**SUMIF Example**: 

Using `=SUMIF(B:B, "_.apelabs.net", A:A)`

would return 5 in your sample data (again assuming your image includes the only instances of *"_.apelabs.net"*).

This example of the `SUMIF` function is the same as saying, "each time a cell in `Column B` (i.e. `B:B`) **equals** *"_.apelabs.net"*, ***sum*** together the values in `Column A` (i.e. `A:A`) that are located in the same row as each *"_.apelabs.net"* found in `Column B`."

Additionally, you can also use a pivot table, as @ScottCraner suggested. It's all a matter in how you want to present your findings.

Comment: Just to tag on, the duplicate check is: `=If(Countif($A$1:$A1,$A1)>1,[formula])`